# No definition for GetEnumerator

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a beginner really and not quite grasping why I have this issue. I am wanting fill a drop down menu with names from the Types model. I am using the Types model as a lookup referencing a parent table. Below is my Types model. I know I am missing something glaringly obvious but experience isnt on my side here

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MaskFit.Model
    {
    public class Types
        {
        [Key]
        public int TypeId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }


        }
    }
```

And here is my page where I am attempting to implement a foreach but running into an error shown below

[image]

```
@model MaskFit.Pages.MaskList.CreateModel 

@{


    <h2 class="text-info">Create New Mask Fitting</h2>
    <br />
    <div class="border container" style="padding : 30px;">
        <form method="post">
            <div class="text-danger" asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-2">
                    <label asp-for="MaskFittings.Surname"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <input asp-for="MaskFittings.Surname" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <span asp-validation-for="MaskFittings.Surname" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-2">
                    <label asp-for="MaskFittings.FirstName">First Name</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <input asp-for="MaskFittings.FirstName" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <span asp-validation-for="MaskFittings.FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-2">
                    <label asp-for="MaskFittings.TypeId">Mask Type</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 form-group">
                    <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" asp-for="MaskFittings.TypeId">
                        <option selected disabled>Choose...</option>
                        @foreach (var type in Model.Types)
                        {
                    <option value="@type.TypeId">@type.Name</option>
            
                        }
                    </select>
                    @*<input  class="form-control" />*@
                </div>
```

Comment: I suspect your `Model.Types` property should be of type `List<Types>` or something like that - and you probably want to change the name of `Types` to `Type` as it's a *single* type.

Comment: In order to provide us with a [MCVE], you should include the class definitions. We need to see how `CreateModel ` is defined.

Comment: Add using System.Collections to your project.  You only have the Generic one.

Comment: @jdweng And how would that help in this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

You change your model Types class to:

```
public class MyType
    {
    [Key]
    public int TypeId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }


    }
```

and add new model class for View

```
public class ModelForPage
{
    public List<MyType> Types { get; set; }
}
```

Property Types is data source for your select control in page.

Comment: That should do  the trick, might also point out that this will also need matching changes to the controller action. It'd also use `IEnumerable<T>` over `List<T>` here.